# Allow int between 0 -100 else ask agian

Tags: python

Hi try to do a program that asks the user for a number and only allow an int between 0-100
If not, i want to ask the same question agian. EDIT I try to do a program that asks a user for a number then the user have to type a nuber between 0 - 100 if not question i asked agin. If the user type a sting it will generates a other message and then ask the user to enter a number between 0 -100. if the nuber is correct i want to break out of the loop. EDIT2 Problem solved! Thanx for quick help from every one. I am a noob on this...

```
print('Whats your name?')
name = input()
print('Hello ' + name + ' enter a number between 0 - 100')

number = input()
while True:
    try:
        if  0 <= int(number) <= 100:
            print('Good')
            break
        else:
            print('You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100')
            continue
    except ValueError:
            print('You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want the program to ask the user to a enter a valid value. But this program cuses an infit loop..

Comment: @Maak you should accept if you are satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `while num < 0 or num > 100`

```
print("What's your name?")
name = input()

print('Hello ' + name + ' enter a number between 0 - 100')

try:
    num = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print('You must enter a number between 0 - 100')

while num < 0 or num > 100:
    try:
        num = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print('You must enter a number between 0 - 100')

print('Good')
```

**Example of output:**

```
What's your name?
'John Doe'
Hello John Doe enter a number between 0 - 100
200
120
300
50
Good
```

Comment: I understand this program. But i also want to tell the user that they type a number out of range and also handle if they writ a string. Thanx for your support!

Comment: Take a look at the edit, I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the `input()` inside the while loop. Here is a verbose code:

```
def take_int_as_input(default=-1):
    try:  
        return int(input())
    except:
        return default

print('enter a number between 0 - 100')
num = take_int_as_input()
while 0 > num or num > 100:
    print('You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100')
    num = take_int_as_input()
else:
    print "Good"
```

Paste the above code in a file with a name `code.py`. The following is the output:

```
$ python code.py 
enter a number between 0 - 100
d
You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100
gf
You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100
rfe
You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100
876543
You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100
22
Good
```

---

A concise and less verbose version:

```
print('enter a number between 0 - 100')
while not (0 <= take_int_as_input() <= 100):
    print('You must enter a nuber between 0 - 100')
else:
    print "Good"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
print('Whats your name?')
name = input()

while True:
    number = input()
    try:
        if 0 <= int(number) <= 100:
            print('Good')
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('You must enter a number between 0 - 100')
```

`input()` should be inside while loop

Comment: why continue is needed at last line ?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, you are right, continue doesn't need. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function defined by a **recurrence** :

```
def ask():
    num = int(input("Enter your number between 0 and 100"))
    if num < 0 or num > 100:
        ask()
    else:
        print('Good')
        pass
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use recursion when a simple loop will do, because Python doesn't eliminate [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), and there's a recursion depth limit.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks a lot for your feedback !